# Swift 3 IBM Lotus Domino authentication

Tags: swift, authentication, lotus-domino

I am very new to XCODE and iOS and I can't figure out how to do an authentication on IBM Domino server. I am trying to do a simple app to get some data from the server.
This is the latest version of my attempt. Bear in mind, that couldn't find information on what IBM Domino server needs. But I've done tons of authentications with javascript. I've deliberatly left the commented part, which is one of the attempts to do a login.

```
func doLogin(){
    print("entered doLogin")
    let myUrl: String = "https://url.com/names?login"
    guard let url = URL(string: myUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }
    var request = URLRequest.init(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let params = ["Username":String(describing: self.username), "Password":String(describing: self.password)]
    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    //URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in
    //  if let safeData = data{
    //      print("response: \(String(data:safeData, encoding:.utf8))")
    //  }
    //}

    //let postString = "Username=\(String(describing: self.username))&Password=\(String(describing: self.password))"
    //request.httpBody = postString.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)
    request.timeoutInterval = 30.0

    //print(request)

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration : configuration)
    //let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self as! URLSessionDelegate, delegateQueue: nil)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {
        (data : Data?, response:URLResponse?, error) in
        // check for any errors
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error calling POST on url")
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        // make sure we got data
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")

            return
        }

        do {
            print ("responseData:")
            print(responseData)
        }
    }
    //print ("response:")
    //print(task.response)
    task.resume()
```

Comment: "what IBM Domino server needs" depends on the configuration of the Domino server. It supports basic authentication, a couple of different form-and-cookie session authentication methods, and several SSO configurations. You need to (a) talk to the admins of the Domino server, and/or (b) try logging in from a browser and analyze what is sent/received.

Comment: Well.. With javascript just username and password are enough.
Here is an example of my working dojo xhrPost. And I think that RedirectTo is optional:

 dojo.xhrPost({ 
                url: '/names.nsf?login', 
                content: {
     "username" : dojo.byId("#{id:cc_login_panel_username}").value,
     "password" : dojo.byId("#{id:cc_login_panel_password}").value,
     "RedirectTo": "\\icons\\view.gif"
     }, 
                load: function (data) {

Comment: That works because the Domino server you are connecting to is configured to use standard session authentication. It won't necessarily work for other Domino servers, but I'm glad you have a solution.

Comment: No the problem is, I can't get any response with the code I posted. So what I am really asking is if this code is even correct. And since I am new with Swift and iOS, i am not sure this is how it is done.

Comment: The only answer to that question is that might be correct, or it might not be. You need to have information about how your Domino server is configured, and you probably need to test it yourself using a browser - to see exactly what the Domino server is sending to the browser when you attempt to open a URL for a resource that requires authentication.